# How to return value of variable from async JS function in React Native

Tags: javascript, dom, react-native

I'm trying to load an external URL into a React Native app and then extract the `<title>` element from it. I don't want to use the [WebView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview.html) as this should happen in the background. I'm using the [dom-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser) library to achieve it. However, an I'm not able to return the value of `product_name` from `findproduct()`. When running the function, it does log the correct value of `product_name` in the console, indicating that the code is working fine. But the problem arises when I want to take the value of `product_name` outside `findproduct()` and use it elsewhere.

```
async function findproduct(){
  var DomParser = require('dom-parser');
  var parser = new DomParser()
  const html = (await (await fetch(product)).text()); // html as text
  var dom = parser.parseFromString(html);
  const product_name = dom.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].innerHTML;
  console.log("name="+product_name); //this logs correctly
  return product_name;
}
productname = findproduct(); //this logs something else
console.log(productname);
```

Here, `productname` is either undefined or something like `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`. I searched around but all I understood was that there is some other way to return variables from an `async function`. Nothing else. I need to insert `productname` into a DB. So, I need the exact value. I also tried to give a delay but to no gain. And in this case, the delay doesn't even seem to work. It just logs `productname` first and then logs `product_name`.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  productname = findproduct(product);
  console.log(productname);
},5000)
```

What am I doing wrong with that async function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `async` functions return a `Promise` instead of the actual value. So, to get the actual value, you have to do it like this.

```
findproduct().then((productname) => console.log(productname))
```

If you want to do something, you may use it like this...

```
findproduct().then((productname) => {
  //do what you want to do with productname
})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sennen Randika is correct, I am just adding resources so you can learn more about this because async functions and promises are really important to learn for JavaScript and in general.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

[https://javascript.info/async-await#:~:text=Async%20functions&text=The%20word%20%E2%80%9Casync%E2%80%9D%20before%20a,in%20a%20resolved%20promise%20automatically.&text=So%2C%20async%20ensures%20that%20the,wraps%20non%2Dpromises%20in%20it](https://javascript.info/async-await#:%7E:text=Async%20functions&text=The%20word%20%E2%80%9Casync%E2%80%9D%20before%20a,in%20a%20resolved%20promise%20automatically.&text=So%2C%20async%20ensures%20that%20the,wraps%20non%2Dpromises%20in%20it).

Comment: @Vishal DS I highly recommend you to go through the above links to get a proper understanding of handling async functions and Promises.